# Perl: getting the maximum length of a value in a perl, better than O(N)?

Tags: perl

```
my $max_cs = 0;
foreach my $cs (values %{$j{$type}}) {
    $max_cs = length($cs) > $max_cs ? length($cs) : $max_cs;
}
```

Can the above be done in better than O(N)? Maybe in a different data structure other than a hash?

Is a priority queue shareable between threads?

Can [Hash::PriorityQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::PriorityQueue) be shared between threads using [threads::shared](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads::shared)?

Comment: priority queue. if i push based on the length of  $CS, PQ will keep it in order so it would be O(1) for pop. but im not sure if its shareable

Comment: im using threads::shared

Comment: I think this might need a bit more clarification what you're trying to accomplish and why. You're iterating keys and values in a hash, which may not be exactly what you're after. I don't think you can find the longest any more efficiently than O(N) simply because one way or another, you need to inspect every element at least once.

Comment: Adding the N items to the queue is at least O(N)

Comment: im okay with insertion being O(N)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You asked if finding the longest using a PQ would take less than O(N). The answer is no.

Comment: yes it would. its just a pop which is O(1).

Comment: No, O(N + 1) = O(N). And I just checked. Inserting into Hash::PriorityQueue is far worse than O(N) because it checks if the item is already in the queue. That makes it O(N^2)!!!

Comment: Inserting happens on a separate thread which i dont care about

Comment: Inserting can be worse than O(N) for all i know. In this context, pop is a separate operation from insertion. and now pop is O(N) since im iterating. i want it to be less than than if possible

Comment: i was just thinking of different ways while writing this question., i think using PQ is "a" way or maybe using other data structures. but im not sure if such data structure is thread-safe and sharable.

Comment: You can make a thread-safe PQ.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have threads processing a number of items in order of length. The best way to do that would be to sort the strings by length and use a Thread::Queue. Then, the workers will start working on the items in the right order. They might finish in the wrong order, though, You'll need more if you wish to prevent that. We can't help you if you don't tell us what your problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to get the length of the longest string in a list, [`List::Util::max`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#$num-=-max-@list) will be significantly faster than the code you've shown, although still O(N).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Actually, that's [slower](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a5b893f1540492ed2e4)

Comment: @ikegami I ran your benchmark three times and maxmap was the winner every time. Granted, the margin was smaller than I got with my own benchmark earlier, but still...

Answer (score 4):

> Can the above be done in better than O(N)? Maybe in a different data structure other than a hash?

No, finding the longest of N items can't normally be done in less than O(N).

With no extra information, it's impossible to find the longest of N elements in less than O(N) time since it requires getting the length of all N strings. Dividing the work between threads divides the work by a factor, so the best solution remains O(N).

If you have extra information, then a solution that's better than O(N) could possibly be devised. For example, if the strings are sorted by length, there exists an O(1) solution.

> Is a priority queue shareable between threads?

Any data structure can be made thread-safe.

> Can [Hash::PriorityQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::PriorityQueue) be shared between threads using [threads::shared](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads::shared)?

No.

Comment: but whats the cost for sorting the string?

Comment: Sorting can be as good as O(N log N), but it's O(N^2) using Hash::PriorityQueue because it checks for duplicates entries.

Comment: Turns out sorting can be as good as O(N) in this particular case (`push @{ $sorted[ length($_) ] }, $length for @inputs;`) because we can effectively compare one element to all elements at once.

Answer (score 1):

To discover the longest hash value, every value has to be measured and compared. That is an O(N) operation.

Computer processors don't really do several things at once - the software just makes it seem that way. So unless you have a way of using multiple processors simultaneously, your idea will simply waste time splitting the process into multiple threads that cannot be executed in parallel.

Parallelism is generally useful only for something like IO operations that *can* run simultaneously.

If you are having problems with the speed of execution, then your best solution is to keep a separate sorted list of the hash values as the hash is created, if that is possible.